# How to find X, Y and Rotation value of a UIView after CATransform3D applied

Tags: ios, swift, calayer, catransform3d

I have a UIView on my screen. I am applying layer.transform to that view with translation and rotation according to users tap movement using tap and rotation gesture. At last i want to retrieve the final x and y position with the rotation separately. Could not find any such post here to get those information from transform. Can anyone help with this?

Here is the code am using to apply the transform.

```
var transform = CATransform3DIdentity
transform = CATransform3DTranslate(transform, displacementX, displacementY, 1.0)
transform = CATransform3DRotate(transform, gesture.rotation, 0, 0, 1.0)

self.currentItem.imageView.layer.transform = transform
```

Comment: did you try this  _baseLayer valueForKeyPath:@"transform.rotation.z"] for rotation

Comment: no i did not tried this..let me try first.

Comment: no, this does not returns the rotation degree or any value. its just 0

Answer (score 1):

Please refer the following code,

**For Applying Transform,**

```
let degrees = 90.0
let radians = CGFloat(degrees * Double.pi / 180)
sampleView.layer.transform = CATransform3DMakeRotation(radians, 0.0, 0.0, 1.0)
```

**To get rotation angle after transform,**

```
let radiansFromSampleView = atan2(sampleView.transform.b, sampleView.transform.a)
let DegreesFromRadiansOFSampleView = CGFloat(180 * Double(radiansFromSampleView) / Double.pi)
```

For x and y positions you can directly take from frame of the view even after transformation.

Hope this can be helpful.

Comment: sorry bro...this returns 0 always. even there is rotation applied. also the frame origin is not the position where my view is currently.

Comment: Actually above code is working fine for me, thats why i have shared, Can you please share your block of code.

Comment: am not using cgaffinetransform. am using catransform3d. this is why your code does not returns anything to me.